# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url','zlip','fs','path' in '[TEST_LIB_PROJECT]\node_modules\[LIB_NAME]\dist\esm'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-component, rollupjs, npm-package

I am building a React component library in typescript. The library is supposed to use and build on top of the following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.0.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.39.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  }
```

As direct dependency, and it has also development dependencies as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^23.0.2",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "^5.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/yup": "^0.32.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "rollup": "^3.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-scss": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
}
```

I have a rollup config file as follows:

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import dts from "rollup-plugin-dts";
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import json from "rollup-plugin-json";
import copy from "rollup-plugin-copy";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";

export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.ts",
    output: [
      {
        file: "dist/cjs/index.js",
        format: "cjs",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
      {
        file: "dist/esm/index.js",
        format: "esm",
        sourcemap: true,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      commonjs(),
      resolve(),
      json(),
      typescript({ tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json" }),
      postcss(),
      copy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: "src/index.css",
            dest: "dist",
            rename: "index.css"
          },
          {
            src: "README.md",
            dest: "dist",
            rename: "README.md"
          },
          {
            src: "package.json",
            dest: "dist",
            rename: "package.json"
          }
        ]
      })
    ],
  },
  {
    input: "dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
    external: [/\.css$/],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

I could build the library though there are some cirular dependencies warnings, and i coud also publish it to both `npm` and `github` scoped package repo.

But when i test the library eaither with direct install from npm or github i have the folliwin errors:

- Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url','zlip','fs','path' in '[LIB_PATH]\dist\esm'

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.